# Run command that requires UAC trough command line

Tags: virtualization, uac, virtualbox

I have a bunch of virtual machines that I need to update from time to time. I found this VirtuaBox command

VBoxManage guestcontrol

that works great. problem is that updating requires UAC. Is there any way to bypass the UAC check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to do it quickly was to buy this software:

http://www.ntwind.com/software/hstart.html

If I had more time I would probably develop something myself. What the software does is install a scheduled task and then run the program through the scheduled task. A brief description of this can be found here:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, you are requested to type in the root password every time, right?

If so, to bypass that by adding the command to the sudoers file, then when using the command (with sudo) it will not ask for a password but will elevate you to root right away.

To allow a specific program or shell script to run as root but without typing the password (like during boot), add to **/etc/sudoers** the following line:

**(username) ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/cmd**

for example:

```
Mac ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vboxmanage
```

After doing that, when typing **sudo vboxmanage** you will not be ask for root password anymore.

Hope that helps!